# How to pass value from javascript to php controller in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-4

Passing the value from Javascript to php controller in laravel.

I have created as {select}(html element), on a button click using Javascript want to pass the value and {select}(html element) id of newly created element to php controller. So that I can get these value in the controller and insert the value in my DB.

Below is my code:

Javascript code:

```
 function addNew() {
    var count = document.getElementById("skill_count").value;

    $('#skills_table tr:last').after('<tr><td>Skill:</td><td><selectname="newskill'+count+'" id="newskill'+count+'">\n\
    </td><td>Exp.in years:</td><td><input type="text" name="newexperience'+count+'"></td><tr>');
    document.getElementById("skill_count").value= parseInt(count)+1;
    var skill = document.getElementById('newskill'+count);
    $.get('skills_json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = data.skill_id;
            opt.innerHTML = data.skill_name;
            skill.appendChild(opt);
        });
    }, 'json');
}
```

code in controller:

```
 DB::table('userskillmappings')->insert(array(
        'experience' => Input::get("newexperience'+count+'"),
        'user_id' => Session::get('userid')

        ));
```

Route to controller:

```
Route::get( 'skills_json', array( 'uses' => 'MyProfile@skillsReturnJson' ));
```

Comment: just to clarify, you have a `route::get('skills_json'` implemented already, correct?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah, correct.

Comment: Is it working with less complicated concatination? There is a lot going on and a lot that can go wrong. I mean does your AJAX get work with hardcoded values like `'experience' = 2, 'user_id = 1', 'skill_id = 1'` just to check if everything is setup correct. :)

Comment: Perform the click function, then open your web inspector, go tot he network tab. On this tab, you'll see the ajax request, click it and find the "clean url". Paste that into your browser, then start doing normal debugging like `exit('here')` to make sure you're getting into the controller. If you get into the controller, then you know the issue is with the DB query, so dump the `Input` and `Session` vars to make sure they're proper. Keep doing this until you've resolved it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like any of the data is being passed to the server, either as URL parameters in a `get` request or as data in a `post` or `put` request. Larvavel has no way of knowing the value of `$count` in advance.